# Excel : Summation of data that belongs to certain id

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-365

It is easier to illustrate the problem based on the following example:

I have two sheets: mapping and data.

1. The Mapping sheet contains a (one-to-many) mapping table between a country name and the corresponding Group ID:
   [image: Mapping sheet]
2. This table (from the Data sheet) contains the country name with the corresponding GDP:
   [image: table (from Data sheet) mapping country name and year to GDP]

The objective is to create a summary table that maps the Group ID to the sum of GDP (for all countries and all years) in a separate sheet:

[image: summary table that maps the Group ID to the sum of GDP]

I tried to use the `SUM` and `SUMIFS` functions
as recommended [at Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic). 
They propose the following formula based on their own example.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"blue,"red"}))
```

However, the challenge arises due to two reasons:

1. I cannot list down the ID in an array form as I have many ID variations. 
   Also, the actual ID consists of both numbers and alphabets.
2. I must follow a guideline not to merge the tables into a single sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re willing and able to add a helper column to your Data sheet, set `Data!F12` to

```
=INDEX(Mapping!C$4:C$8, MATCH(C13,Mapping!D$4:D$8,0))
```

[image: Data sheet]

and then, on your Summary sheet, set `B3` to

```
=SUMIFS(Data!$E$13:$E$22, Data!$F$13:$F$22, $A3, Data!$D$13:$D$22, B$2)
```

and drag/fill down and to the right.

[image: Summary sheet]